# Running Apache Zeppelin with nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: apache, nginx, websocket, reverse-proxy, apache-zeppelin

In our current architecture we have two apache front servers, in front of them, we have an nginx load balancer. And in front of that an nginx reverse proxy.

My problem is that i'm trying to run Apache Zeppelin through the reverse proxy, and i'm having some problems with the websockets.

I get an error like this : `400 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL`

And here is a screenshot of what the Chrome's Networks tab shows :
[image]

I add my reverse proxy config for Zeppelin:

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log  warn;
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /zeppelin/ {
        proxy_pass http://zeppelin:8080/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
    }

    # fallback
    location / {
        return 301 http://ci.blablalablab.com/app/;
    }  
}
```

Zeppelin is running inside a docker container, and i have exposes the 8080 port, its host name is : zeppelin.

If you have any questions on the architecture or so, don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you very much guys !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add to your reverse proxy configuration

```
location /ws {  # For websocket support
    proxy_pass http://zeppelin:8080/ws;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}
```

Reference: [Zeppelin 0.7 auth docs](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/security/authentication.html)

Comment: This is not working for latest version of Zeppelin and Nginx. Any ideas? I tried with same configuration as of yours.

Comment: I actually just used it for Zeppelin 0.8.2 + Nginx 1.16.1 and it worked as expected

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of digging around, i ended up with this configuration :

```
location /zeppelin/ {
    proxy_pass http://zeppelin:8080/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
}


location /zeppelin/ws {
    proxy_pass http://zeppelin:8080/ws;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

This is working pretty good, thank you everyone for your efforts ;)

Comment: This is not working for latest version of Zeppelin and Nginx. Any ideas? I have the same configuration as of yours.

Comment: I did not work with Zeppelin since then, i hope you found a solution :D